# Does git push origin always merges to master branch?

Tags: git, terminal

So Initially when I clone the repo it has two branches

```
*master
*develop
```

Then on my local machine I create a new branch from develop

```
git checkout develop
git checkout -b feature/new-feature
```

I am done with all the commit on my local machine and I want to it to merge with develop branch on github again.

```
git push origin feature/new-feature
```

Does this gonna create a pull request to merge into develop branch or master branch?

Comment: Note that `git push` never actually *merges* anything at all. It sends *commits* from your Git repository, to some other Git repository. The commits to send are the ones you made that they don't have yet, strung together in a chain by the process by which you made them. Then, having sent those commits, your Git now asks their Git to set one of its branch names to *remember* the *last* commit in that chain-of-commits. Since they won't have a `feature/new-feature` branch yet, you can just ask them to create it, to remember the last commit in that chain of commits.

Comment: Now that *their* repository has the commits, you can ask someone (some human) to merge those commits. That request, *please merge these commits*, is a "pull request". If you're using GitHub or Bitbucket or similar, they usually have a web interface for creating these pull requests.

Comment: This question is ambiguous: Title asks for _merge_, body for _creating PR_. Please [edit] to _clarify and focus_!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It won't create a Pull Request automatically.

It just pushes the branch to the remote.

If you want to have a pull request, you will have to create it yourself, except if you have a scriot that does it for you.

You can decide what target branch to use when creating the pull request.

Note that pull requests are a feature of some git servers (like GitHub) and not (directly) a feature of git.

Pushing the new branch will create that (exact same) branch on the server. If you want to merge it in an existing branch, you can do this either local(`git merge` command) or by creating a new pull request if the server supports it.

Comment: Which branch does it gonna push it to?

Comment: It will create a new remote branch aka a new branch on the server.

Comment: Oh okayy !! So I can choose on github which branch I want it to get pulled into?

Comment: Yes, and you can even directly merge it locally using the `git merge` command.

Comment: Oh okay, I will mark this answer as accepted. Can you help me one with one more thing, since I cant create a new question till 90 minutes. Is there any way to know the parent branch? How to know which branch I was on when I created a new branch?

Comment: `git log` displays you the last commits (normally on your current branch) and it will also show you if a branch points to one of the commits. If the branch moved further, you may want to use `git branch --graph --all`.

Comment: And if you e.g. use GitHub and go to the branch, it will display something like `a commits ahead, b commits behind <branch>`. But keep in mind that git does not know about parent branches(only parent commits). At the end, a branch ist just a reference to a commit(a file containing the hash of the commit and a newline).

Comment: @AdityaVerma: Git's branches do not record a "base" or "parent" branch. GitHub's pull requests do; you choose the base branch at the time you make the pull request. GitHub have an algorithm to pick a base branch automatically, and it tends to be right most of the time, but in some cases you might have to change the base they (GitHub) selected for you.

Answer (score 2):

`git push origin feature/new-feature` will create a push to your new branch `feature/new-feature`. Not in `master` or `develop` branch

If you want all changes in the `develop` branch, you must merge from `feature/new-feature` branch like `git merge develop`.

Nice explaining  -> [www.freecodecamp.org](https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/push-a-new-local-branch-to-a-remote-git-repository-and-track-it-too/13222)